# Setting a timer on Attiny1604

Tags: arduino, attiny

My goal is to generate timer interrupt on Attiny1604. I don't need a specific frequency right now, I just need to understand the inner workings and get it under control. I will be using the 16-bit timer A.

**My problem**: (If the corresponding interrupts are enabled) I will get a ~217 kHz square wave on the output, but nothing happens if I modify any of the registers (different prescaler, different compare value, etc) the output will always be the same 217 kHz square wave.

If I understand the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATtiny804_1604-Data-Sheet-40002028A.pdf) correctly, I am supposed to do several things:

1. Enable timer interrupts:

```
/* Timer control register
    [0] = Enable
    [2:0] = Prescaler
    - Prescaler 0x2 = /2
    - Prescaler 0x4 = /16
*/
TCA0.SINGLE.CTRLA = (1 << 0) | (0x4 << 1);
```

2. Set frequency mode and enable CMP0EN:

```
TCA0.SINGLE.CTRLB = (1 << 0) | (1 << 4);
```

3. Set compare (CMP0) value:

```
/* Timer Comare register0
    Value to compare against TOP (CNT)
*/
TCA0.SINGLE.CMP0L = 0b0010;
TCA0.SINGLE.CMP0H = 0b0011;
```

4. Enable CMP0 interrupt:

```
TCA0.SINGLE.INTCTRL = (1 << 4);
```

Then, to monitor the output, I've made this:

```
volatile int set_output = 0;

ISR(TCA0_CMP0_vect)
{
    // digitalWrite(4, !digitalRead(4));
    if (set_output == 0)
    {
        PORTB.OUT = 0x0f;
        set_output = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        PORTB.OUT = 0x0;
        set_output = 0;
    }   
}
```

Whole code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

volatile int set_output = 0;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
    
    cli();

    /* Timer Counter register
        TOP (current) value of counter?
    */
    TCA0.SINGLE.CNTL = 0;
    TCA0.SINGLE.CNTH = 0;

    /* Timer Comare register0
        Value to compare against TOP (CNT)
    */
    TCA0.SINGLE.CMP0L = 0b0010;
    TCA0.SINGLE.CMP0H = 0b0011;

    
    /* Timer control register
        [0] = Enable
        [2:0] = Prescaler
        - Prescaler 0x2 = /2
        - Prescaler 0x4 = /16
    */
    TCA0.SINGLE.CTRLA = (1 << 0) | (0x4 << 1);

    TCA0.SINGLE.CTRLB = (1 << 0) | (1 << 4);

    TCA0.SINGLE.INTCTRL = (1 << 4);

    sei();
}

void loop()
{
}

ISR(TCA0_CMP0_vect)
{
    // digitalWrite(4, !digitalRead(4));
    if (set_output == 0)
    {
        PORTB.OUT = 0x0f;
        set_output = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        PORTB.OUT = 0x0;
        set_output = 0;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many cycles does your timer isr take to execute? Multiply this number by 217000. What is the result? I'd guess a number that is greater than the clock speed of your cpu. Thus your cpu is tied up servicing interrupts and not doing anything else useful.

Short answer: don't try to interrupt the cpu at 217kHz.

Comment: I understand, but I don't know how it is generating the 217kHz - Or how can I change that to generate any other frequency, like around 10kHz. I'm digging more into it - maybe I need to clear the interrupt flag in ISR (tried, but failed)?

Comment: yes, you need to clear the interrupt flag as per the datasheet. 
TCA0.SINGLE.INTFLAGS = (1 << 4);

Comment: You are right, it works now!